# Laravel 9:Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null in for loop

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I have a form the containes 5 files which name is "feature_photo_1","feature_photo_2","feature_photo_3","feature_photo_4","feature_photo_5" . So with this im trying to use a for loop to optimize my code . but when i execute the code it gives me the error of

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null
```

Here is my controller code

```
# Insert feature_photos
for ($i=1; $i < 5; $i++) { 
    if($request->featured_photo_.$i)
    {
        $file = $request->file('featured_photo_'.$i);
        $filename = date('YmdHi') . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move(public_path('upload/featured_project/'), $filename);
        $fphoto->featured_photo_.$i = $filename;
        $fphoto->save();
    }
}

$fphoto->save();
```

I doubt there is a mistakes i put on `$file = $request->file('featured_photo_'.$i);` but im dont know how to fix it . Hope can get yours opinion for this problem . Thank you in advance ,Any answer/opinion are appreciated .

---

code for form

```
    <form action="{{route('charity.profile.feat-project.new.store')}}" id="add_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group mb-3 row">
                                <!-- Project Name -->
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <label for="name" class="form-label">*Featured Project Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"
                                        value="{{old('name')}}" placeholder="Enter name of the project">
                                    @error('name')
                                        <div class="text-danger">
                                            {{ $message }}
                                        </div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <!-- Cover Photo -->
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="cover_photo" class="form-label">
                                            Cover Photo
                                            <span data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Must not exceed 2mb." data-bs-original-title="yes">
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-information-outline"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="cover_photo" id="cover_photo" type="file">
                                        @error('cover_photo')
                                            <div class="text-danger">
                                                {{ $message }}
                                            </div>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-3 row">
                                <div class="col-md-9 mb-3">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <!-- Date of Activity -->
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="started_on" class="form-label">*Date of Activity:</label>
                                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="started_on" id="started_on"
                                                value="{{old('started_on')}}" placeholder="Enter date of the activity">
                                            @error('started_on')
                                            <div class="text-danger">
                                                {{ $message }}
                                            </div>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- No. of Beneficiaries -->
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="total_beneficiaries" class="form-label">No. of Beneficiaries (Optional):</label>
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="total_beneficiaries" id="total_beneficiaries"
                                                value="{{old('total_beneficiaries')}}" min="1" max="1000" placeholder="Choose between 1 to 1000...">
                                            @error('total_beneficiaries')
                                            <div class="text-danger">
                                                {{ $message }}
                                            </div>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <!-- Sponsors -->
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="sponsors" class="form-label">Sponsors (Optional):</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sponsors" id="sponsors"
                                                value="{{old('sponsors')}}" placeholder="Enter sponsors...">
                                            @error('sponsors')
                                            <div class="text-danger">
                                                {{ $message }}
                                            </div>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- Venue -->
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="venue" class="form-label">Venue (Optional):</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="venue" id="venue"
                                                value="{{old('venue')}}" placeholder="Enter venue of the project...">
                                            @error('venue')
                                            <div class="text-danger">
                                                {{ $message }}
                                            </div>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Preview of Cover Photo -->
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <img id="show_cover_photo" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Cover Photo Preview" src="{{ asset('backend/assets/images/placeholder-image.jpg') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group mb-5 row">
                                <!-- Project Objective -->
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="objective" class="form-label">*Objective:</label>
                                    <textarea id="elm1" rows="7" name="objective" placeholder="Enter your project's objective/s..."
                                        maxlength="500">
                                        {{old('objective')}}
                                    </textarea>
                                    @error('name')
                                        <div class="text-danger">
                                            {{ $message }}
                                        </div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <!-- Thanksgiving Message -->
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="message" class="form-label">Thanksgiving Message (Optional):</label>
                                    <textarea id="elm2" rows="7" name="message" placeholder="Enter your thanksgiving message to the sponsors..."
                                        maxlength="500">
                                        {{old('message')}}
                                    </textarea>
                                    @error('name')
                                        <div class="text-danger">
                                            {{ $message }}
                                        </div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="text-muted font-size-12 mt-2">
                                    <em>
                                        Recommended image size is <strong>* 1920 x 380 </strong>
                                        Must not exceed 2MB.

                                    </em>
                                </p>
                            </div>


                            
                            <div class="row" data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'>
                                <div class="form-group mb-3 row">
                                    <!-- Featured Photo 1 -->
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="featured_photo_1" class="form-label">Featured Photo 1</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="featured_photo_1" id="featured_photo_1" class="form-control">
                                        @error('featured_photo_1')
                                            <div class="text-danger">
                                                {{ $message }}
                                            </div>
                                        @enderror
                                        <!-- Preview -->
                                        <div>
                                            <img id="showImage1" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Featured Project Photo Preview" src="{{ asset('backend/assets/images/placeholder-image.jpg') }}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Featured Photo 2 -->
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="featured_photo_1" class="form-label">Featured Photo 2</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="featured_photo_2" id="featured_photo_2" class="form-control">
                                        @error('featured_photo_2')
                                            <div class="text-danger">
                                                {{ $message }}
                                            </div>
                                        @enderror
                                        <!-- Preview -->
                                        <div>
                                            <img id="showImage2" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Featured Project Photo Preview" src="{{ asset('backend/assets/images/placeholder-image.jpg') }}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Featured Photo 3 -->
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="featured_photo_3" class="form-label">Featured Photo 3</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="featured_photo_3" id="featured_photo_3" class="form-control">
                                        @error('featured_photo_3')
                                            <div class="text-danger">
                                                {{ $message }}
                                            </div>
                                        @enderror
                                        <!-- Preview -->
                                        <div>
                                            <img id="showImage3" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Featured Project Photo Preview" src="{{ asset('backend/assets/images/placeholder-image.jpg') }}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Featured Photo 4 -->
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="featured_photo_1" class="form-label">Featured Photo 4</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="featured_photo_4" id="featured_photo_4" class="form-control">
                                        @error('featured_photo_4')
                                            <div class="text-danger">
                                                {{ $message }}
                                            </div>
                                        @enderror
                                        <!-- Preview -->
                                        <div>
                                            <img id="showImage4" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Featured Project Photo Preview" src="{{ asset('backend/assets/images/placeholder-image.jpg') }}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Featured Photo 5 -->
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="featured_photo_5" class="form-label">Featured Photo 5</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="featured_photo_5" id="featured_photo_5" class="form-control">
                                        @error('featured_photo_5')
                                            <div class="text-danger">
                                                {{ $message }}
                                            </div>
                                        @enderror
                                        <!-- Preview -->
                                        <div>
                                                 <img id="showImage5" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Featured Project Photo Preview" src="{{ asset('backend/assets/images/placeholder-image.jpg') }}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row px-5">
                                <ul class="list-inline mb-0 mt-4 float-end">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-rounded w-lg waves-effect waves-light float-end" data-bs-target="#bs-add-modal-center" data-bs-toggle="modal">
                                        <i class="ri-edit-2-line"></i> Submit
                                    </button>
                                    <a class="btn list-inline-item float-end mx-4" href="{{ url()->previous() }}">Cancel</a>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="float-end row p-3">
                                <p class="text-muted font-size-12 mt-2">
                                    <em>
                                        <strong>*Featured projects are subject for approval by Caviom </strong>
                                        before it can be displayed on your Charitable Organization's public profile.
                                        The processing times for approval may usually take from 2 to 3 working days.
                                    </em>
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

Comment: One of your files is not posting, maybe a typo in the name of one of your inputs? I wonder why you don't use `feature_photo[]` as name and a foreach? that would solve the problem, and make it easier to maintain. Can you add the HTML for the inputs?

Comment: @GertB. Hi, I have already update my question above with the html code for the form .

Comment: photo 4 has a wrong `for` attribute in the label.  you should check if `$file` is not NULL in your controller code. (empty file input)

Comment: ok i have update the for attribute for the photo 4 but it still get same error . i think there is still something missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to read a dynamic property you can not just use `.` here:

```
$request->featured_photo_.$i
```

Instead you need to create a variable and use that in the attribute call:

```
$fileInputName = 'featured_photo_'.$i;
$request->$fileInputName;
```

your 5th input will not be processed as is :

```
for ($i=1; $i < 5; $i++) {
```

will only go to 4.

full code:

```
for ($i=1; $i < 6; $i++) { 
    $fileInputName = 'featured_photo_'.$i;
    if($request->$fileInputName)
    {
        $file = $request->file($fileInputName);
        $filename = date('YmdHi') . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move(public_path('upload/featured_project/'), $filename);
        $fphoto->$fileInputName = $filename;
        $fphoto->save();
    }
}
```